# Make GitHub's README look different on smartphones and desktops using only HTML (CSS is restricted)

Tags: html, css, github, readme

I have a GitHub project with `README.md` file. I embed an image in the following way

```
<img src="./logo.svg" align="right" width="180px">
```

Here is [an example](https://github.com/Shpota/goxygen) of such an image.

*Note:* GitHub allows using embedded HTML but not CSS, that's why I am using `width` property instead of css.

This way the image occupies the right side of the screen allowing to put text on the left side.

**Problem:** If you open such link on a smartphone there is too less space for the text and it looks bad with split words or letters that take the whole line. It would be great if I could use larger `width` specifically for mobile devices. But GitHub restricts usage of CSS in markdown files and I can't use `@media` queries.

**Question:** How to make GitHub's README look different on mobile and desktop without using CSS?

Comment: mybe try somthing like this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images

Comment: @MatanSanbira thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately it didn't help - I guess the GitHub's markdown compiler removes the options, because in the end html there are no other options except the main one. Or maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: @SashaShpota Using `<img src="/docs/images/certified_kubernetes_color-222x300.png" align="right" height="80vh">` gives an interesting and responsive visual. if you're ever interested ;)

Comment: The width attribute should be an integer without unit.

Answer (score 0):

[`udacity/responsive-images`](https://github.com/udacity/responsive-images) is:

- a GitHub page project, visible at [`udacity.github.io/responsive-images/`](http://udacity.github.io/responsive-images/)
- with a page dedicated to responsive images, [with examples](http://udacity.github.io/responsive-images/examples/).
  For instance: "[Two images, 50% width with margin](http://udacity.github.io/responsive-images/examples/1-07/twoImages50pcWithMargin/)", seen in [`examples/1-07/twoImages50pcWithMargin`](https://github.com/udacity/responsive-images/tree/38898a1f2f1f638eefb2fc1e3967348314a77eb0/examples/1-07/twoImages50pcWithMargin)

Check in [their viewport directives](https://github.com/udacity/responsive-images/search?q=viewport&unscoped_q=viewport) would be enough to implement a responsive image, combine with their inline CSS style.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
```